# Are there any function for Fisher's Linear Disciriminant Analysis(FLDA) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, classification

I used fitcdiscr function for my classification problem. I know that fitcdiscr function is used for linear discriminant analysis(LDA). I also want to use Fisher's LDA. Are there any function in MATLAB. I could not find.

Comment: You need to provide more context in what you are willing to accomplish here...

Comment: "Linear discriminant analysis is also known as the Fisher discriminant, named for its inventor, Sir R. A. Fisher", https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/discriminant-analysis.html